# How to get rid of the space/ enter of the input buffer in vim?

Tags: c, buffer

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    struct st{
        char n[100];        //Name
        char d[100];    //lastname

    } arr[4];

    void add(int *c, struct st l[])
    {
        int i                   =*c;
        int arrSize             =sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

        if((*c)<arrSize)
        {
            printf("Enter a name :\n");
            fgets(l[i].n, 100,stdin);
            printf("Enter lastname :\n");
            fgets(l[i].d,100,stdin);
            printf(" SUCCESS. Person was added\n");
        }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int ct                               =0;
        int *ctPointer=&ct;
        char response                          ;
        char endWhileloop                   =0;

        while(endWhileloop==0)
        {
            printf("To add a person to the list hit 'a'  \n");
            printf("to end program enter 'q'\n");
            fgets(&response,2,stdin);
            fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);

            switch(response)
            {
            case 'a':
                add(&ct, arr);
                break;

            case 'Q':
                endWhileloop=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\nbye.");
        return 0;
    }
```

I am trying to run my code in an older version of Vim(maybe an older version of C) for my school. Unfortunately I am not certain what version they are running

Surprisingly, my code works from home using vim and eclipse. but not from school

```
:I tried--->    fgets,  scanf("%[^\n]s",name) , scan( %c,&name), fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END),flush(stdin);
```

But nothing has worked for me. I would like to know of some possible solutions.

When I run my code from school(not home), after I enter  'a' my code prints: Enter  name..(line in between) Enter last name. 
Without taking an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this line instead of `fseek`

After getting the option you are not clearing the input buffer. so this is the reason for the not getting the first input.

After entering the first input new line will be there in input buffer. After processing first input then buffer will give the \n.

So place this line after getting the option. Declare the variable `int c;`

```
while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c!= EOF );
```

Then make the `case` into like this,

```
case 'a': case 'A':
         ...
         ...
case 'q': case 'Q':
         ...
         ...
```

For getting the option you can use simply the `scanf` like this.

```
 scanf(" %c",&response);
```

Comment: Thanks  A LOT, you are correct. you solution clears the buffer as I intended too. I would give you good feedback but my reputation is only 6.